# Проблема с циклом while и cin

Tags: циклы, while, cin

Цикл пропускает всю часть кода кроме `cin >> a;` в условии.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float num = -1, a = -1;
    int j = 0;
    cin >> a;
    while (a != 0) {
        if (a / num > 1) {
            num = a;
            cin >> a;
            if (a > num) {
                j++;
            }
        }
        else {
            cin >> a;
        }
        num = a;
    }
    cout << j;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего не работае эта часть

```
if (a > num) {
    j++;
}
```

Ты пытаешься сравнить одинаковые числа
Попробуй заменить > на >=